# Markitup javascript will not load

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, markitup

I'm using markItUp! for BBCodes on my website. It worked fine before, but after rearranging a few things it suddenly stopped working, and I have no idea why.
It doesn't help when I revert my changes, unless I'm missing something.

I have this in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jquery['plugins']['markitup'].'jquery.markitup.js'; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $jquery['plugins']['markitup'].'sets/bbcode/set.js'; ?>"></script>
<link href="<?php echo $jquery['plugins']['markitup'].'skins/simple/style.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo $jquery['plugins']['markitup'].'sets/bbcode/style.php'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Despite that, the markItUp function is undefined in any other script.

Firebug tells me that it is loaded just fine, but it's still not working.

Everything else is working perfectly, even the bbcode settings (the other js file) are defined like they should.

I have no idea what it might be, so if you need to know anything else, please ask.

Comment: Don't know what's causing the problems, but if reverting your changes doesn't fix it, I'd track that down first.  Make sure you're clearing or disabling the cache in your browser.

Comment: Make sure jQuery is being loaded before the markitup script.

Comment: jQuery is being loaded, all my other scripts work.
I've tried clearing session and cache, no luck.
Thanks

Comment: make sure jQuery only being loaded once, an extra load after any plugins will wipe them out

Comment: It is only being loaded once, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, it was a stupid mistake. I misplaced a few binds. Sorry ^^

Comment: @charlietfl : *My* stupid mistake was precisely the second one you pointed out, i.e., loading jQuery twice -- because I hastily created a Jinja template extension without paying enough attention to what my base template had already loaded. (In my case, Javascript threw the error "markItUp is not a function." Maybe this can be a tipoff for someone else who sees the same error.)